# Solving a sets problem with fractions.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In a group of students, each student is taking a mathematics course or a computer science course or both. One-fifth taking a mathematics course are also taking a computer science course, and one-eight of those taking a computer science course are also taking a mathematics course.

Are more than one-third of the students taking a mathematics course?

In order to solve the problem given I've tried doing the following:

> - X: Are those taking a mathematics course or a computer science course or both.
> - 1/5 X: Mathematics and Computer Science (M $\cup$ CS)
> - 1/8 X: Computer Science and Mathematics (CS $\cap$ M)

Based on the "variables" stated above we can create an equation to find X (Universal Set)

> X + $\left(\frac15\right)$X + $\left(\frac18\right)$ X equals to 53/40 X.

Then, I couldn't find out how to proceed does anyone know how to do so? Any help would be very welcomed.

Comment: Let $M$ be the number taking jst math, $C$ the number taking just comp, $B$ the number taking both. $B$ is one-fifth of $B+M$, and $B$ is one-eighth of $B+C$. And now you have to work out whether $(M+B)/(M+B+C)$ is bigger than $1/3$. Go for it.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Still working my brains off trying to solve this, but I haven't succeed. Thanks for answering anyways I appreciate it.

Comment: Can you use my comment to write down two equations?

Comment: Yes, but I'm not sure whether it's okay. For instance my guessing about the two equations you addressed is: B = 1/5(B+M) + 1/8(B+C) ,  (M+B)/(M+B+C) = 1/3 ... then, I'd solve for B the 1st equation and replace B into the second one, but I'm sure  there's "something" or everything's wrong.

Comment: Where do you get $(1/5)(B+M)+(1/8)(B+C)$? Where does that plus sign in the middle come from? And why do you write $=1/3$, when I said the question is whether the quantity is bigger than $1/3$?

Comment: 1/3 because I thought the equivalence would be okay considering it as "greater than or equals to" and the plus sign because of...well yes it doesn't seem logic. I put it in the middle because I related "both" with the plus sign. Actually, I read an example where the unknown value is found by just simply using sums, so I guess I got confused.

Comment: OK, so what should you be writing down instead of what you wrote down?

Comment: It's an inequation " $(M+B)/(M+B+C)  > 3$", isn't it? About the other two terms, since it's not a sum I sincerely don't understand where it would come from.

Comment: How did $1/3$ become $3$? What equation do you get from "$B$ is one-fifth of $B+M$"?

Comment: How had 1/3 become 3? That was a silly typo, I didn't realize. The equation I get from "B is one-fifth of B+M" is B = 1/5(B+M)"

Comment: Good! Now, you can use that equation to get $M$ as some number times $B$. Then you can do the same kind of thing with "$B$ is one-eighth of $B+C$" to get $C$ as some number times $B$. Then you can replace both $M$ and $C$ in $(M+B)/(M+B+C)$ and get a number out of it.

Comment: I did so and it worked out somewhat. It proved that the inequality was true, but I didn't get a specific value like $X>6/5$ , I just got something like $3 > 1/2$ which is true and I guess it's enough to prove what's been asked. You should post this as the solution so I can select this as best answer. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm happy for you to write it up and post it as an answer. Good practice for you.